# Remover coluna de zero de um array

Tags: r

Tenho um array tridimensional e dentro desse array há outro array de zeros e quero removê-lo do array maior. Por exemplo,

```
set.seed(1)
a = rnorm(60)
b = array(a, dim = c(10, 2, 5))
b[, , 4] = matrix(rep(0, 20), ncol = 2)
b[, , 2] = matrix(rep(0, 20), ncol = 2)
```

O resultado que eu desejo é um array com
    `a[ , ,1], a[ , ,3], a[ , ,5]`, ou seja, removendo

`a[ , ,2]` e `a[ , ,4]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você precisa simplesmente remover os elementos da array, pode fazer da mesma forma que faria com vetores ou matrizes, ou seja, utilizar o sinal de menos com o índice dos elementos que quer remover:

```
b2 <- b[,,-c(2, 4)]
```

Uma solução mais dinâmica seria detectar automaticamente qual matriz (dentro da array) possui apenas 0.  Uma possibilidade é usar o `apply` na terceira dimensão e verificar se todos elementos são zero:

```
b3 <- b[,,!apply(b, 3, function(d) all(d == 0))]
```

Note que ambos levam ao mesmo resultado:

```
> identical(b2, b3)
[1] TRUE
```

É claro que, ao remover os elementos, a nova array passa a ter apenas 3 matrizes, por assim dizer, pois os valores nas posições 2 e 4 não podem ser nulos ou vazios.